# Visual Studio 2017 (ASP.NET Core) and Aurelia (ES6) from scratch manually?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, aurelia, dotnet-cli

Is there a tutorial somewhere that shows you how to install & build Aurelia **MANUALLY** in Visual Studio 2017?

Why do this?

1. Ideally I'd like to use bundleconfig.json for as much as I can and
   use gulp for those things I can't do in bundleconfig.json.
2. I'll learn every aspect of the build/bundle/package process as possible instead of having a tool set that up for me. (Makes things
   easier to troubleshoot if I know how it is all setup.)
3. I won't be dependent on CLIs and packages that are not kept up to date. (Several that I've looked at are based on VS 2017 RCs).

I've tried several CLIs and "skeleton" projects but they all have their issues.  Some haven't been updated to use the latest csproj.

**Aurelia CLI:** Project/Folder structure doesn't mirror any standard way of building SPAs that I've seen.  Also doesn't mirror what you get when using Aurelia's own "Skeleton Project."

**dotnew new spa templates:** Though the most promising it's typescript only and not ES6.  (Maybe there is a way to switch it easily?)

**Aurelia's Skeleton Projects** It adds dependencies that I do not need.  It also does not work out of the box.

Comment: I think you should go for dotnetcore spa templates. If you don't know typescript, you should :) you will like it. Otherwise, typescript covers ES6, too. You can develop using ES6 but you just have to have .ts files instead of .js

Comment: @HasanAyan - Yeah I want to stick with ES6 for now.

Comment: What is "dotnew new spa templates"? You imply that it supports Aurelia in an ASP.NET Core project using Typescript. This is _exactly_ what I've been looking for. Do you have a link?

Comment: Never mind I found it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

Comment: I've created and have been meticulously updating an aurelia + typescript + systemjs with aurelia-cli (not jspm) at this github project: https://github.com/diegohb/samples-aurelia-vanilla_cli  ..  my goal was to be able to walk commit by commit, organized in a branch-per-task manner, and be able to read commetns along with diffs to easily show other developers how to setup an aurelia project "from scratch" .. check it out, might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what I've determined since originally writing this question.

**My original thoughts with lessons learned:**

Why do this?

1. Ideally I'd like to use bundleconfig.json for as much as I can and
   use gulp for those things I can't do in bundleconfig.json.

   **Answer:**  I was only doing this because I was trying to embed Aurelia inside of a web api project in Visual Studio.  I recommend you don't do this and instead keep it as a separate project.  (Separation of concerns)
2. I'll learn every aspect of the build/bundle/package process as possible
   instead of having a tool set that up for me. (Makes things easier to
   troubleshoot if I know how it is all setup.)

   **Answer:**  Though building from scratch would help me learn about this more it isn't a major roadblock.  I was just inexperienced with more modern UI frameworks and their corresponding build processes. (RTFM)
3. I won't be dependent on CLIs and packages that are not kept up to date. (Several that I've looked at are based on VS 2017 RCs).

   **Answer:** - That happens no matter what route you go.  You can wait for a library to mature more if this is a big concern.

The bottom line is my question was based on some incorrect thinking.  If you are trying to go this route you really need to ask yourself why and determine if it is worth it.  To me it was not.  Just go with what works, learn and move on.  Oh and don't resist Typescript!

Answer (score 1):

1. npm install aurelia-cli@0.30.1 --global
2. create new vs solution in 2017 (ASP.NET Core Web App)
3. with command prompt, cd into the solution root dir (not wwwroot)
4. au new --here
5. select RequireJS or SystemJS (my personal preference)
6. select option 2, asp.net core
7. select the remaining options.
8. Run f5 in VS2017.

Comment: why not the project folder? acording to docs (http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/2) it should be project folder containing project file.

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer the question as to how to setup the project manually.